# JS not working properly on iOS devices - Only sometimes

Tags: javascript, css, ios

> I have searched here for weeks now trying to find an answer. I haven't
>   seen anything that duplicated my problem, but I have tried a few
>   things anyway, either because they were close, or out of desperation.
>   So, here I am asking specifically.

I have a members area on my site that offers the players a notepad to keep notes. It is a simple thing, just a PHP write to flat file that uses JS to show or hide the pop up.On every tested device, screen size, resolution, OS, etc.it works perfectly.

I have the same code and pop ups on the side bar in the gaming area. In all Linux and Windows OSes, browsers, mobile or desktop screens it works perfectly, yet, on iPhone, iPad and Mac computers with Safari, the pop ups are there (this is verified, the players can click the links, write and save notes, etc) but the pop ups don't appear. They are just... invisible.

I am not a JS expert, nor am I exceptional at PHP, but I feel I am simply missing something here that is stupid-obvious.

I hope someone can see what I am missing. Again, this code works as expected Page A, but Not Page B, even though it is the same code. The pop ups in iOS devices the boxes are there on Page B, just invisible.

```js
// Notepad PopUp
var note = document.getElementById('myNote');
var btn = document.getElementById("noteBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  note.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  note.style.display = "none";
}

// Help Links PopUp
var links = document.getElementById('myLinks');
var btn = document.getElementById("linksBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  links.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  links.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == links) {
    links.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.note, .links, .donate {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 padding-top: 40px;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.note-content, .links-content, .donate-content {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #888;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 25em;
 height: 30em;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
 -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
 animation-name: animatetop;
 animation-duration: 0.4s
}
/* Don't forget the drop down animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
 from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
 to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
 from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
 to {top:0; opacity:1}
}
/* and the close buttons, if applicable */
.close, .close2, .close3 {
 color: #FFF;
 float: right;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus, .close2:hover, .close2:focus, .close3:hover, .close3:focus {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
/* Next we need the header, body, content and footers */
.note-header, .links-header, .donate-header {
 min-height: 4em;
 padding: 2px 16px;
 background-color: #999;
 color: #000;
 position: relative;
}

.note-header p, .links-header p, .donate-header p {
 color: #000;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.note-body, .links-body, .donate-body {
 padding-top: 1em;
}

.note-body p, .donate-body p {
 padding-top: 1em;
}

.links-body p {
 padding-top: 1em;
 font-size: 1.25em;
 margin: 0.5em auto;
}

.links-body a:link, .links-body a:visited, .donate-body a:link, .donate-body a:visited {
 color: #2D5986;
 background: inherit;
}

.links-body a:hover, .donate-body a:hover {
 color: #0099CC;
 background: inherit;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

textarea {
 font-family: "Courier New", Georgia;
}
 
.info {
 font-size: 8pt;
 font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="topRight">
     <ul>
      <li><button id="forumBtn" class="curs">Member Forum</button></li>
      <li><button id="memberBtn" class="curs">Member Portal</button></li>
      <li><button id="noteBtn" class="curs">Open Notepad</button></li>
      <li><button id="linksBtn" class="curs">Open Help Tools</button></li>
      <li><button id="donateBtn" class="curs">Donate </button></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
 <div id="myNote" class="note">
  <div class="note-content">
   <div class="note-header">
     <span class="close">&times;</span>
     <p>Member's Notepad</p>
   </div>
   <div class="note-body">
     <p><form action="/pge.php" method="POST" name="note">
         <textarea name="note" rows="20" cols="40">Hi! I'm a notepad!
</textarea>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Note">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="delNote" value="Delete Note" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do that?');"></form>
    </p>
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div id="myLinks" class="links">
  <div class="links-content">
   <div class="links-header">
     <span class="close2">&times;</span>
     <p>Help Tools: Links and Resources</p>
   </div>
   <div class="links-body">
     <p><a href="http://example.com/Tools/" target="_blank">Tools</a></p>
     <p><a href="http://example.com/tools/" target="_blank">more Tools</a></p>
     <p><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank"> Converter</a></p>
     <p><a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">Google Search</a></p>
     <p><a href="https://www.ecosia.org/" target="_blank">Ecosia Search</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="myDon" class="donate">
  <div class="donate-content">
   <div class="donate-header">
     <span class="close3">&times;</span>
     <p>Ways to Help CWoT 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class="donate-body">
     <p><a target="_blank" href="https://example.com">Donate</a><br><span class="info">a $3 (USD) donation</span></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div><script src="../scripts/notepad.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] WITHOUT PHP - it is not a PHP question. You need to add some touchstarts instead of click and use addEventListener instead of onclick

Comment: That's wonderful news! I have no idea what any of that means.

Comment: 1. click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60681257/edit)

Comment: 2. Click the button that looks like this `[<>]`

Comment: 3. Paste RELEVANT HTML (NOT PHP) into the top left pane, RELEVANT css into the top right pane and the script into the bottom left pane - click TIDY and save  - we now have a [mcve]

Comment: Then we can change your script to use [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and add the [touchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) that mobile is using and test in Safari

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have done as requested. I just don't know what is relevant and what isn't since everything works just fine on one page but not another.

Comment: I think I cut the html off before all the JS was used. It should run now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. NEVER call anything submit in a form. If you ever want to programatically submit it, the submit event handler is not available to you
2. You REDEFINE btn - it will be the second button always - this is a real error.
3. I strongly suggest using querySelector and addEventListener
4. The problem is likely a CSS issue on the page in question

Tested in Safari 13.0.5 (15608.5.11) on OSX 10.15.3 Catalina

Images

[image]

[image]

The code will look like this:

```js
// Notepad PopUp
var note = document.getElementById('myNote');
var noteBtn = document.getElementById("noteBtn");
var closeNote = document.querySelector(".close");
noteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  note.style.display = "block";
});
closeNote.addEventListener("click", function() {
  note.style.display = "none";
});

// Help Links PopUp
var links = document.getElementById('myLinks');
var linksBtn = document.getElementById("linksBtn");
var closeLinks = document.querySelector(".close2");
linksBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  links.style.display = "block";
});

closeLinks.addEventListener("click", function() {
  links.style.display = "none";
});

window.addEventListener("click",  function(event) {
  if (event.target == links) {
    links.style.display = "none";
  }
});

document.querySelector("[name=delNote]").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to do that?')) e.preventDefault();
  })
```

```css
.note,
.links,
.donate {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.note-content,
.links-content,
.donate-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #888;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25em;
  height: 30em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Don't forget the drop down animation */

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* and the close buttons, if applicable */

.close,
.close2,
.close3 {
  color: #FFF;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus,
.close2:hover,
.close2:focus,
.close3:hover,
.close3:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Next we need the header, body, content and footers */

.note-header,
.links-header,
.donate-header {
  min-height: 4em;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #999;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.note-header p,
.links-header p,
.donate-header p {
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.note-body,
.links-body,
.donate-body {
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.note-body p,
.donate-body p {
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.links-body p {
  padding-top: 1em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}

.links-body a:link,
.links-body a:visited,
.donate-body a:link,
.donate-body a:visited {
  color: #2D5986;
  background: inherit;
}

.links-body a:hover,
.donate-body a:hover {
  color: #0099CC;
  background: inherit;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

textarea {
  font-family: "Courier New", Georgia;
}

.info {
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="topRight">
    <ul>
      <li><button id="forumBtn" class="curs">Member Forum</button></li>
      <li><button id="memberBtn" class="curs">Member Portal</button></li>
      <li><button id="noteBtn" class="curs">Open Notepad</button></li>
      <li><button id="linksBtn" class="curs">Open Help Tools</button></li>
      <li><button id="donateBtn" class="curs">Donate </button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="myNote" class="note">
    <div class="note-content">
      <div class="note-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Member's Notepad</p>
      </div>
      <div class="note-body">
        <p>
          <form action="/pge.php" method="POST" name="note">
            <textarea name="note" rows="20" cols="40">Hi! I'm a notepad!
</textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="subBut" value="Save Note">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="delNote" value="Delete Note" /></form>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myLinks" class="links">
    <div class="links-content">
      <div class="links-header">
        <span class="close2">&times;</span>
        <p>Help Tools: Links and Resources</p>
      </div>
      <div class="links-body">
        <p><a href="http://example.com/Tools/" target="_blank">Tools</a></p>
        <p><a href="http://example.com/tools/" target="_blank">more Tools</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank"> Converter</a></p>
        <p><a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank">Google Search</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.ecosia.org/" target="_blank">Ecosia Search</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myDon" class="donate">
    <div class="donate-content">
      <div class="donate-header">
        <span class="close3">&times;</span>
        <p>Ways to Help CWoT 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="donate-body">
        <p><a target="_blank" href="https://example.com">Donate</a><br><span class="info">a $3 (USD) donation</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="../scripts/notepad.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the details. I will redo the code and wait for my Apple testers to come back online to verify. I will let you know.

Comment: Tested with the new code by those on Safari and the problem persists. The code is called, the boxes work, but remain invisible. Only on these pages. The other instance of the buttons and code in the other part of the site work just fine.

Comment: Reload the answer to see images from my iMac based on the code I posted

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work. The code has always worked. It works on Page A of the site, but not on Page B. In Safari/Mac/iPhone/iPad, the code works as expected in the member area of the site. On the level area of the site, the same code doesn't show the boxes. They are there...the visitor can interact with them, they are just invisible.

Comment: I would need to see the site. If you do not want to post it here, my website is in my profile. Sounds like a CSS issue

Comment: email sent. Thank you.

Comment: Ended up I was just an idiot. CSS positioning hiding divs in Safari. Anyway, thanks for helping me fix and understand JS a little more in the process.

Comment: There was a js error too. Two var btn would make the first onclick disappear